# Inference on served tensorflow model fails with float input

Tags: json, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to run inference on a served tensorflow model. More specifically, sending a JSON request through REST to get a prediction.

I'm actually just doing the basic example outlined here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/

Everything works properly, except when I change the "instances" input to floats that don't end in '.0', it fails.

`curl -d '{"instances": [1.1, 2.2, 5.3]}' \
   -X POST http://localhost:8501/v1/models/half_plus_two:predict`

**{ "error": "Failed to process element: 0 of \'instances\' list. Error: Invalid argument: Cannot convert JSON value: 1.1 to float without loss of precision." }**

For my eventual model though, I will need to pass floats through the JSON request. I also tried to send it using python, using simplejson to serialize the Decimal when sending the request.

I'm assuming it can't parse the float properly when trying to load the JSON. Is this something that has to be coded in the graph of the model? (note that I didn't code the graph/model so I'm not too familiar with it)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just came across this error too. It's a [bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/commit/01c2fb804161125bebda0b5880657ad046ab2da7) in Tensorflow Serving `1.11`, a fix has already been made just not released yet.

To work around this for now, you can install the previous version, tag `1.10.0`, of the Tensorflow Serving image instead of the latest.

```
docker pull tensorflow/serving:1.10.0
```

Just, make sure that have removed the latest image and are running the correct version tag like below.

```
➜ docker images
REPOSITORY           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
tensorflow/serving   1.10.0              a7b9844ed1ae        2 months ago        215MB
```

Your curl request with payload containing `float`s should work now.

Comment: thanks :) I figured it out too in the meantime. What I did was actually pull the tf-nightly instead, didn't know it worked with 1.10 as well!